# Electron client IP

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using the following code to retrieve the client IP in my electron application:

const fnOSIP = () => {
const nets = networkInterfaces();
const results = Object.create(null); // or just '{}', an empty object

```
    for (const name of Object.keys(nets)) {
        for (const net of nets[name]) {
            // skip over non-ipv4 and internal (i.e. 127.0.0.1) addresses
            if (net.family === 'IPv4' && !net.internal) {
                if (!results[name]) {
                    results[name] = [];
                }

                results[name].push(net.address);
            }
        }
    }
    return results; 
}
```

The problem is that it's returning two IP's.  I would like to get the primary but not quite sure.

[image]

If I do a command: ip address I can get the following information of each IP:

```
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:d2:3e:a5:46:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.117/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
   valid_lft 4944sec preferred_lft 4944sec
inet6 fe80::7701:3d92:db95:9fdc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



16: br-f5f2e5a5a382: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:23:09:cb:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-f5f2e5a5a382
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:23ff:fe09:cbc9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The br-f5f2... is from docker:

Would it make sense to assume that if it has /24 it's the primary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, you have to strip the internal Addresses. I use this script to terieve the IP of a Client:

```
function getIPs() {
    var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    let ipAdresse = {};
    Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (ifname) {
      let alias = 0;
      ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
      if ('IPv4' !== iface.family || iface.internal !== false) {
        // skip over internal (i.e. 127.0.0.1) and non-ipv4 addresses
      return;
    }

    if (alias >= 1) {
    // this single interface has multiple ipv4 addresses
    console.log(ifname + ':' + alias, iface.address);
    } else {
    // this interface has only one ipv4 adress
    console.log(ifname, iface.address);
    ipAdresse = {IP: iface.address, MAC: iface.mac};
    }
    ++alias;
  });
});
return ipAdresse;
}
```

The Problem (and I could not find a solution for that) is, if the machine has two interfaces (like LAN and WIFI enabled at the same time) you cannot determine which is which.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about the Wifi and Lan issue.  Unfortunately, your code is loop  is landing on both those IP address but just returning the last one

Comment: You can easily change it to return an Array of found, non internal Addresses. But there is no way to find out which Address belongs to which interface. Or at least I did not find a suitable solution.